# How do I solve ClassNotFoundException in a eclipse rcp build?

Tags: eclipse-juno

I have build an eclipse feature project in eclipse juno and when I launch the program from the IDE everything is fine, no errors in the console.

When I export the product it runs but it does not show the content of the parts that I created in the Application.e4xmi file (only a grey background). When I check the configuration folder in the exported folder there is a log file with following errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-19 19:22:13.859
MESSAGE Unable to load class 'be.yt.diepvriezer.ui.handlers.ExitHandler' from bundle '2'
```

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-07-19 19:22:13.859
>   !MESSAGE Unable to load class 'be.yt.diepvriezer.ui.handlers.ExitHandler' from bundle '2'
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: be.yt.diepvriezer.ui.handlers.ExitHandler
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>   .....

And so on for every handler and part that I created in the application model.

I checked the build.properties and manifest files and everything is there.

Can somebody point me in the right direction how to solve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution, just things to check:

When you look at the `plugins/` subdirectory of the exported product, does it contain the plugin for your `be.yt.diepvriezer.ui.handlers.ExitHandler`?
If not, that plugin needs to be added to the product. When you launch an RCP product from within the IDE, all plugins in the workspace are usually included, but when you export a product, you really need to list all plugins that you really want to include in the `*.product` file (directly or via `*.feature`s)

When you un-zip that plugin jar file, is the `...ExitHandler` class really in there? If not, something failed in the product export.

Is the `Application.e4xmi` that refers to your `..ExitHandler` in that same plugin as the code? If not, then the code within the 'other' plugin that provides the `..ExitHandler` is not accessible by the class loader of the plugin that contains the `Application.e4xmi`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Check of plugin folder: it contains the correct plugin's I unzipped the jar file and the class is inside. The Application.e4xmi file is inside the plug-in that contains the handler code.

Comment: Again, no solution, just guessing what to check next. Indeed puzzling. When you use the eclipse IDE for RCP development, it includes the source code. So you could open the `BundleLoader` class (Menu Navigate, Open Type, ...), set a breakpoint in the `findClassInternal` method, maybe a conditional breakpoint for `name.equals("be.....ExitHandler")` and try to figure out why it fails. The `BundleLoader.bundle` for example should probably point to the bundle that contains the ExitHandler. Maybe in the debugger you get some hint as to why it's not finding the class: Looking in the wrong bundle?

Comment: The crux is of course that for this you'll have to attach the IDE's debugger to the exported product, because within the IDE it all seems to work OK.

Comment: This is what I did: I created a new workspace and copied the java code to the new workspace (re-created the plugins). Then with the new workspace I created a new build. The build is working OK. I am going to try to find out what went wrong in the original workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need to launch the app with "-clean", or define "osgi.clean=true" to make sure you clear cached dependencies. Launching in a clean workspace will have the same effect (no cached values):

"any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches."

More info [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).